# NSTextView can't see the main menu's font menu

Tags: cocoa, macos, nstextview, nsmenu

For some very strange reason, none of our texts views can receive bold, italic, show fonts, etc. messages from our menu or keyboard shortcuts.

We have a main menu nib that has our app delegate as its delegate.  The app delegate loads up a window controller, which has it's own nib.  The window controller loads up a view controller from ITS own nib.  In the view controller, we programmatically add NSTextViews to the screen.  How can we get these text views to talk with the main menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text view needs to be in the responder chain, which it normally will be if the user clicks on it.

Make sure you connected your menu items to the First Responder fake object, not to any specific real object in the nib (such as your controller). If you set their targets to a specific object, they will always target that object, even if it can't respond to the actions. You need to set it to the First Responder so that their action messages—and validation messages—will travel down the responder chain and hit any responder that can and should respond to Bold, Italic, and Show Fonts messages.